How can I run a binary server on Azure Web App?
I have a Go project that runs on port 8000 and I'm trying to build it on Azure DevOps and then deploy to a Linux Azure Web App.
But when I try to access the page, it shows ":( Application Error" and in the most of my attempts basic the error says "Container didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8000"
DevOps
pool:

  name: Azure Pipelines

  timeoutInMinutes: 30



steps:



- task: GoTool@0

  displayName: 'Use Go 1.22.2'

  inputs:

    version: 1.22.2



- task: Go@0

  displayName: 'go get'

  inputs:

    arguments: '-d'

    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'



- task: Go@0

  displayName: 'go build'

  inputs:

    command: build

    arguments: '-ldflags="-s -w" -o build'

    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'



- task: ArchiveFiles@2

  displayName: 'Archive $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build'

  inputs:

    rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build'

    includeRootFolder: false



- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4

  displayName: 'Azure App Service Deploy: MyServerProject'

  inputs:

    azureSubscription: 'Visual Studio Enterprise: ...'

    appType: webAppLinux

    WebAppName: MyServerProject

    packageForLinux: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'

    RuntimeStack: 'DOTNETCORE|7.0'

    StartupCommand: 'my-server'

    AppSettings: '-PORT 8000 -WEBSITES_PORT 8000 -WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT 1800'

Log
2024-05-06T19:44:07.724140609Z    _____
2024-05-06T19:44:07.734185163Z   /  _  \ __________ _________   ____
2024-05-06T19:44:07.734190363Z  /  /_\  \\___   /  |  \_  __ \_/ __ \
2024-05-06T19:44:07.734193663Z /    |    \/    /|  |  /|  | \/\  ___/
2024-05-06T19:44:07.734196563Z \____|__  /_____ \____/ |__|    \___  >
2024-05-06T19:44:07.734199763Z         \/      \/                  \/
2024-05-06T19:44:07.734203064Z A P P   S E R V I C E   O N   L I N U X
2024-05-06T19:44:07.734206264Z
2024-05-06T19:44:07.734208964Z Documentation: http://aka.ms/webapp-linux
2024-05-06T19:44:07.734211764Z Dotnet quickstart: https://aka.ms/dotnet-qs
2024-05-06T19:44:07.734214564Z ASP .NETCore Version: 7.0.13
2024-05-06T19:44:07.734217364Z Note: Any data outside '/home' is not persisted
2024-05-06T19:44:09.748366682Z Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd.
2024-05-06T19:44:10.140172606Z Starting periodic command scheduler: cron.
2024-05-06T19:44:10.149816058Z Running oryx create-script -appPath /home/site/wwwroot -output /opt/startup/startup.sh -defaultAppFilePath /defaulthome/hostingstart/hostingstart.dll     -bindPort 8000 -bindPort2 '' -userStartupCommand 'my-server'
2024-05-06T19:44:10.341022895Z Could not find build manifest file at '/home/site/wwwroot/oryx-manifest.toml'
2024-05-06T19:44:10.369622450Z Could not find operation ID in manifest. Generating an operation id...
2024-05-06T19:44:10.369672950Z Build Operation ID: 054d28e9-d3b7-43b9-8e77-ea26b35fa7fd
2024-05-06T19:44:11.658474634Z
2024-05-06T19:44:11.658510434Z Agent extension
2024-05-06T19:44:11.658515034Z Before if loop >> DotNet Runtime
2024-05-06T19:44:11.670287898Z DotNet Runtime 7.0Writing output script to '/opt/startup/startup.sh'
2024-05-06T19:44:11.949309510Z Running user provided startup command...
2024-05-06T19:44:11.949361811Z my-server: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by my-server)
2024-05-06T19:44:11.949386711Z my-server: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by my-server)
2024-05-06T19:44:05.685Z INFO  - 7.0_20240321.5.tuxprod Pulling from appsvc/dotnetcore
2024-05-06T19:44:05.706Z INFO  -  Digest: sha256:***
2024-05-06T19:44:05.706Z INFO  -  Status: Image is up to date for 10.1.0.5:13209/appsvc/dotnetcore:7.0_20240321.5.tuxprod
2024-05-06T19:44:05.724Z INFO  - Pull Image successful, Time taken: 0 Seconds
2024-05-06T19:44:05.925Z INFO  - Starting container for site
2024-05-06T19:44:05.926Z INFO  - docker run -d --expose=8000 --name myserverproject_123312 -e WEBSITE_USE_DIAGNOSTIC_SERVER=true -e PORT=8000 -e WEBSITES_PORT=8000 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=myserverProject -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=myserverproject.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=*** -e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 appsvc/dotnetcore:7.0_20240321.5.tuxprod my-server
2024-05-06T19:44:09.424Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container myserverproject_123312 for site myserverproject
2024-05-06T19:44:13.018Z ERROR - Container myserverproject_123312 for site myserverproject has exited, failing site start
2024-05-06T19:44:13.044Z ERROR - Container myserverproject_123312 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8000, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2024-05-06T19:44:13.057Z INFO  - Stopping site myserverproject because it failed during startup.

It this possible to achieve? If so, what could I be missing here?

https://github.com/microsoft/Oryx/issues/1522

I noticed that you add a comment in the GitHub issue but no response so far. Maybe you can create a new issue to ask the question. By the way, if you deploy it from your local, without using the Azure DevOps, will the same issue happen?  If the same issue happens, maybe you need to check your code or App Service configurations to find out if there are something wrong.

Based on the logs you’ve provided, it seems that it requires GLIBC version 2.32 or 2.34, but these versions are not found in the Docker image.
2024-05-06T19:44:11.949361811Z my-server: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by my-server)
2024-05-06T19:44:11.949386711Z my-server: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by my-server)

You can check this question Error /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found to solve this error first and see if the issue is still there.
